# How to find the closest date in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to display the values of `ApmaksasApmers` (which is a Reference Value) which are closest to `DateToCompare` in comparison to `GivenDate`

For example:

`DateToCompare` =01.01.2022 and 01.01.2021

and  `GivenDate` = 01.03.2022

I am trying to get the values which come from date 01.01.2022

Here is my code:

```
vm.ApmaksasApmērs.LookupSource  = _nolasītMaksājumusQuery.Nolasīt()
                    .OrderBy(x => x.DateToCompare.Value > vm.GivenDate.Value ? vm.GivenDate.Value - x.DateToCompare.Value : x.DateToCompare.Value - vm.GivenDate.Value)
                    .Select(x => new KeyValuePair<Guid?, string>(x.Id, x.ApmaksasApmērs +" (" + x.PersonasLīdzmaksājumsProcentos + "%)".ToString())) ;
```

Here I am geting an error of `Name:[ApmaksasApmērs],Type:[ReferenceValue],Message:[Don't currently support idents of type TimeSpan]`

Is there a better way of doing this? Thanks in advance

Comment: The error you are getting seems to be related to [NHibernate](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/issues/2707). I think your `OrderBy()` cannot be translated to your DB's query lange and should be done in memory.

Comment: Other than that you query looks ok. You could minimally improve performance by using [`MaxBy()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.maxby?view=net-6.0) instead. `OrderBy()` will sort the whole list even if you only need the closest date. `MaxBy()` will iterate the list only once to find the closest date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did :

1. Create a list for all of the elements:

   ```
   var saraksts =  _nolasītMaksājumusQuery.Nolasīt().Where(x => x.DateToCompare <= vm.GivenDate).ToList();
   ```
2. Find the max value from the list:

   ```
   var maxDate = list.Max(x=>x.DateToCompare)
   ```
3. Find all of the elements where `MaxDate == DateToCompare`:

   ```
   vm.ApmaksasApmērs.LookupSource = list.Where(x => x.DateToCompare== maxDate).Select(x => new KeyValuePair<Guid?, string>(x.Id, x.ApmaksasApmērs +" (" + x.PersonasLīdzmaksājumsProcentos + "%)".ToString()));
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Hi if **DateToCompare** is an array then we compare the absolute value of difference between each el with the given date and when the value is lowest that's the closest date

### Here is how

```
//adding some data
DateTime[] DateToCompare =  {
    new DateTime(2001, 05,05),
    new DateTime(2022,01,01),
    new DateTime(2021,01,01)
    };
DateTime GivenDate = new DateTime(2022, 05, 02);

//Get the absolute value of diference between first el and given date
TimeSpan span = abs(DateToCompare[0] - GivenDate);

DateTime closestDate = DateToCompare[0];
//new we check each el if the dif is lower
for (int i = 1; i < DateToCompare.Length; i++)
{
    if (abs(GivenDate - DateToCompare[i]) < span)
    {
        span = abs(GivenDate - DateToCompare[i]);
        closestDate = DateToCompare[i];
    }
}
//get absolute value
TimeSpan abs(TimeSpan t)
{
    return (t.TotalSeconds >= 0) ? t : -t;
}
Console.WriteLine(closestDate.ToShortDateString());
```